# Is there any way to express $\theta=c$ as some function of $r$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I recently found this: [Desmos Graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). I tried to plot the equation $\theta=45$ but it gave me an error:

> Sorry, you can't graph $\theta$ as a function of anything yet.

[image: Sorry, you can't graph theta as a function of anything yet.]

So I started thinking that how can I make it a functionn of $r$? I tried a lot but I couldn't do it. So please tell how can I make it a function of $r$?

Comment: Is there any way to express $x=c$ as a function of $y$?

Comment: @Lubin That is exactly the same problem.

Comment: Indeed, that was the reason for my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can convert to Cartesian coordinates. For example, if you want to plot $\theta = 45^\circ$, then you can instead plot:
$$
y = \left( \tan \left(45^\circ \cdot \frac{\pi}{180^\circ} \right) \right)x
$$
where we made sure to convert from degrees to radians.

Comment: Thank you for this but I already know that it is simply $x=cy$, but is there no way to do it in polar coordinates?

Comment: No, not that I can think of.

Comment: About 2 days earlier I had seen a formula in some book, but I can't remeber which book it was, but I remember that it used some combination of Tan and arc(something). If I find it again, I will post it here.

Comment: It's probably something like:
$$
\tan \theta = \frac{y}{x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Desmos will draw a plot when you give it the expression $r = \theta,$ 
but not when the expression is written $\theta = r.$
So the answer is, no, if $\theta = 45$ you can't express $\theta$ as a function of $r,$ 
and even if you could, it would not help you.

Comment: In the second part, you said,"and even if you could, it would not help you." But I mean to express it in some way as $r=f(\theta)$ so that it can draw it.

Comment: The whole point is that $r$ *is not* a function of $\theta$.

Comment: @Kartik: The question is apparently misworded, because now you say you wanted to write $r = f(\theta)$, that is, you wanted $r$ as a function of $\theta$, but instead you asked for "it" as a function of $r$, which is a very different thing. I could not read your mind, so I responded to the question you asked rather than the one you wanted answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the answer that you were looking for
$$r \in R$$